# Hibernate relation OneToMany creates by default a not null column. How Can I change it by code?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, one-to-many

I have a class A that holds a 3 lists of class B,C and D with the annotation @OneToMany. The lists can be null when saving an A object.
The created relations table is created with the columns A_hibernateId,  B_hibernateId, C_hibernateId Not null checked on DB (unchecking not null in DB works for saving A objects with null in one of the lists).
I tried many annotations and options but all of them created those columns as not null.

What can I use to create the table with those columns not null option uncheckd?

Class A: (Classes B,C,D doesnt relate back to class A)

```
@Entity
 public class A {
   ....
   private List<B>  bList;
   private List<C>  cLi ;
   private List<D>  dList ;

  @OneToMany
  public List<B> getBList() {
    return bList;
  }
....
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to have **sql tables** with **not null** column and make the _Hibernate_ consider the same column **null**?

Comment: I'm want to be able to put null in those columns, but in creating the table , the "not null" attribute in DB is checked automatically. I tried @column (nullable=true) and the table is still created with those columns as "not null"

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like that ?

@JoinColumn(name="A_ID", nullable=true)

Comment: I did   @Column( nullable=true) and the relations table columns is still created with "not null". (I tried JoinColumn,  didnt create the relations table and created a table I cant delete ...)